# Computing device which is not a stored program device

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

Can you give me one computing device that is not a stored program device?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give me computing devices, too; I like free hardware.

Comment: This seems like a trivia question. What's the problem being solved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any fixed-function hardware is not a stored-program device.

e.g. a hardware h.264 decoder like you find in a GPU is not programmable with an instruction-set.

The output of an adder is probably wired up directly to the input of whatever comes next, rather than routed there by control circuitry based on a stored "instruction".

Fixed-function crypto hardware is also common, e.g. custom [ASICs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application-specific_integrated_circuit) for bitcoin mining, or even just a hardware implementation of AES.

---

An [FPGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-programmable_gate_array) is kind of half-way between a stored-program computer and a fixed-function circuit.  It's programmed into being a specific fixed-function thing, but can be re-programmed.

An FPGA program applies itself to the entire FPGA at once, turning the FPGA into a custom circuit.  The FPGA doesn't read instructions from a stored program one at a time.

Of course, the thing you turn your FPGA into can be a CPU or microcontroller.  In this case the "FPGA program" implements a stored-program computer, but the software analogy of this would be writing an emulator with an interpreter loop (not dynamic recompilation or virtualization).

Comment: @Julius'Web: use the check-mark under the vote arrows to mark one of the answers as "accepted", if you think either of them answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably, the old analog computers used in WW2 submarines, and later in tanks, were fixed function computing machines.

Another really old mechanical example is the [Norden bombsight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norden_bombsight), which was basically an analog computer with aimpoint and gyroscopic inputs connected to the bomber's auto-pilot.

Most things that we think of as non-programmed however merely have programming that we cannot easily access. For example calculators, microwave ovens etc.

A lot of early computing machines were plugboard machines that had to be rewired between computation jobs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugboard  This rewiring took the place of programming.

Comment: Hey, thank you!! :)